# Can you fine tune Falcon instruct models

Tags: llm

Can you fine tune instruction fine tuned LLM like (Falcon 7B instruct and Falcon 40B instruct)? I have seen tutorials where the base models are fine tuned but can't find any which fine tune the instruct models.

Is it recommended or even worth fine-tuning models which have been already instruction fine tuned? If so, are there any considerations regarding training sample size etc?

Also, is Flan-T5 series also instruction fine tuned? There are some tutorials for fine tuning Flan-T5-base and even AWS Sagemaker lists all Flan-T5 models (including XXL) as fine-tunable while Falcon-7B base is listed as not fine-tunable. I wonder why.